# Extending searching into the archives folder in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, folders, archive

When I'm doing a search into my mailbox, Mail is not looking into the archives folder, and that is pretty annoying.

I checked "Look into every folder" into the preferences, but it doesn't change anything. If I want to look into the Archives folder, I have to click on it, and then I can type my search criteria.

Isn't it possible to search into this folder as well when I'm on my main folder?

Comment: Anyone can help me ? I'm feeling alone here. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution fro [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127135/apple-mail-app-hides-archive-folder-how-to-get-it-to-show) that might help:

Alex

> It appears that this is linked to Spotlight in some way.
>
> I recently turned spotlight indexing back on for the volume holding my $HOME and immediately this started working again.
>
> I assume that without the spotlight index it can't find the Archive directly automatically, then finds it via IMAP when I run through the steps in the question.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The thing is, I'm not using spotlight at all, I'm using alfred. But what's the point with spotlight in this case, I'm not sure I understand.
Thanks !

Comment: @guillaumeb, I don't understand either. [sheepish grin]

Comment: @guillaumeb, the solution.

Comment: Great. Let's hope someone is going to help me. Thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: @guillaumeb, just to let you know, I think I will leave the answer there just incase it helps someone who stumbles across this question later.